# CTRL+S is undoing my work in Winforms design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I had some Visual Studio extensions installed which I cleaned up using the following method :

- moved all the settings / etc  (I can't find the SO article I used for directions)
- rebuilt mef cache

Performance is much better now (i guess all those open source libs - fixing em - left a bunch of litter in my settings/cache/internally-dump-all-vs-stuff-here folder), but now I have a very strange problem.

When editing a UI in WinForms (e.g. Add a new form to a project and add a button to it), pressing **CTRL+S** or going to **File > Save [XXX]**  (where XXX is `Form1.cs` for example) -- it undoes everything since my last (alternative save methods that work explained below) save.  For example, if I open the form for UI drag & drop editing, and drop a button on the form, then **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>** or **File > Save [XXX]**, the button and all related code are removed !!

Here is what does work (alternative save methods) :

- If in code view, all saving appears to work as expected
- Using **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>** anywhere works as expected
- Using **File > Save All** anywhere works as expected

I know this might not sound like a large issue, but over the course of a day, I probably use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> hundreds (if not thousands) of times between edits as VS.NET I find very unstable doing things such as random crashes, or other obnoxious things which if not saved (and can't rely on auto-recovery as that doesn't work sometimes) I can lose lots of time.  Currently, this little nuance is starting to cost me time in UI design as I spend more time on UI than in code (code is pretty easy, UI is quirky) and losing all my UI changes / alignments / new objects, because <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is misbehaving, is a real downer.

How can I fix this ?  I have tried repairing, which always seems to cause me hours of headaches getting Xamarin working again -- and I have (as stated) cleared the settings folder, letting VS rebuild and recreate MEF / etc.

Comment: Have you tried `devenv /ResetSettings`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I wish to preserve my code formatting settings, as it's a pain (so much to configure), so if i use that command, I will lose everything.  I am sure there is somewhere to look where this problem may be (manually), I just have no idea where the controller for this is.  Likely it may be Visual Studio Power Tools causing some dorkiness since it does hook CTRL+S to cleanup code, but possible in conjuction with a different setting that it requires or something.  I dunno  lol

Comment: Perhaps try going to Tools Menu->Options->Environment->Keyboard and select some feature and enter cntrl-S in the "Press shortcut keys" and then look at "Shortcut currently used by" dropdown..

Comment: Disabling [Producitivy Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) fixed this problem.   I couldn't find anything in shortcuts.

Comment: @TnTinMn - ok, I have narrowed this down to if a code window is open for the current form I am viewing, it happens. It doesn't seem related to Productivity Tools at all.    This is so quirky XD

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+S has side-effects, it forces all open designer windows to re-initialize themselves.  If there are any bugs in the design-time code that executes (code isn't getting serialized properly, event handlers execute that don't pay attention to DesignMode, exceptions are thrown) then you *will* lose design changes.  In extreme cases VS can crash to the desktop.  Debugging design-time code is the subject of lots of existing Q+A here.

Comment: @HansPassant - this happens on a brand new WinForms project, and only since resetting my settings/etc.  I am really at a loss for what is causing it, but Save All , works, and Save As works from code view (which saves the form) -- example,   new wf project.  double-click form to open code view. go back to form design view, drop a button, CTRL+S .. button vanishes.  Repeat these steps but CTRL+S while on the code window, and the button stays.  It's pretty funky - even a hint as to where something is that is overriding my design save, would be helpful.

Comment: @SamuelJackson, can u post more details about what's happening exactly? like all the changes made are removed ? changes in particular method is removed ? changes made only in particular file is removed ? ,etc., I have experienced code removed in InitializeComponent method

Answer (score 0):

Windows forms designer will remove only the unused code in `InitializeComponent` method of the Form while saving the project.

Undo or pressing `ctrl + z` keys will bring back the deleted codes (A message box will appear asking for confirmation).

**Note**: Press `ctrl + z` immediately after the code gets deleted. Once you close and reopen the file, this may not work

**Why this happens**

When we save the design view of form or entire project, visual studio will serialize all the components in design view and generate code in `InitializeComponent` method. During this process, existing code in the `InitializeComponent` method will be removed. This is why there's a comment saying not to modify the designer generated code.

Comment: Not 'CTRL+Z'  ---  CTRL+*S*  ....  CTRL+Z, is functioning as normal. Please read the question I posted again, including steps to reproduce.  It is strange because this is not normal behavior for this shortcut OR menu command.  Save All, works, Save -- does not, except when in code view, or where no code view has been opened.  Not talking about the designer code-behind source either where the comments don't modify are -- I am talking about ANY code window - including a fresh class.

Comment: @SamuelJackson, I mentioned to use undo or press 'CTRL + Z' immediately to get back the deleted code. (i.e., after pressing CTRL + S)

Comment: Oddly enough, CTRL+Z doesn't work after this either.   Of course I tried that to quickly place my controls back where they were, but --  nada  :S